# Securing website; rewrite any http url to https root

Tags: .htaccess, http, cookies, https, url-rewriting

I'm using a .htaccess in my webspace root:

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=10886400; includeSubDomains; preload" env=HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} http
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L]
```

so that each http url gets redirected to https root.
I want to prevent sslstripping so I'm not redirecting every http url to a https url, but to root url.
Once the user calls a http url (1) and gets redirected to https root, hsts kicks in, so calling that same url (1) results in a secure https url to the wanted resource.

I don't like the first http request being redirected to https root, forcing the user to reenter the request in order to access the resource, so my idea is, to set a secure cookie in the rewrite rule containing the http URI. Once on https root, I read that cookie and redirect to the former requested http uri.

Is this possible? And does this differ from redirecting every http url to the https url?

Comment: I don't see any advantage in all this complex setup, if it is working at all. Simply redirect all requests to the https variant and all is fine. You cannot prevent anyone to make a http request, so to send data unprotected. but you certainly can make sure that you do not accept those and redirect _all_ requests as soon as possible.

Comment: But redirecting every http request to its https variant opens every request for sslstripping. I don't want that. If every http request gets redirected to a single https resource, there's no way sslstripping will succeed.<br>

Comment: I don't understand the issue with that: certainly a client may decide to send a request unencrypted. There is nothing you can do against that. Period. You do not have any control over what a client might do. Also redirecting to your "document root" does not prevent that, how should it? The request _has already been sent unencrypted_ when you get to handle it.

Comment: Of course, I can not influence the clients request. But I can make sure that my servers response is secure.

Comment: No, you can't. That is not how http works, actually. What your rewrite rules do is they send a redirection header back to the client (instead of a response) which asks the client to repeat the request using the https protocol. You see, the protocol selection is done on the client side. The server cannot somehow magically convert a non encrypted request to an encrypted one. It has to ask for a _new_ request.

Comment: Imagine a url a.com/file.ext on a server which is accessible both via http and https. with a 1:1 redirection, a mitm can sslstrip and retrieve that file in clear. With a redirection of every http://a.com/x... request to https://a.com, a mitm never retrieves the file in clear. To retrieve it, he has to use https. So, when I redirect a http://a.com/file.ext to https://a.com after setting a cookie uri=/file.ext and redirecting a https://a.com using the cookie value to https://a.com/file.ext, the only resource available via http is the document root. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, but that simply is not correct. If you rewrite all http requests to https, then the resource / file is _not_ accessible via http. That is the point. The http request will only result in a redirection header being returned.

Comment: Ah, ok, but then I don't understand how sslstrip enables a mitm to access via http...

Comment: That will only work if the server indeed offers access by both protocols, http and https and actually delivers the resource via http. Then a file originally meant to be requested via https can be retrieved via http (thus unprotected). However setting up such an attack is hard, since the ssl certificates check the servers identify. That cannot be spoofed by a man in the middle. That will only work if either the client ignores all warnings about invalid certificates or if the attacker is in possession of the secret server certificate itself and is able to manipulate the network traffic routing.